# How to switch from from the active application on monitor 1 to the active application on monitor 2 via keyboard

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, desktop, spaces, application-switcher

TL;DR: I am typing notes into a full-screen notepad on monitor 1. I want to switch to typing into the visible, full-screen application shown on monitor 2 without using the mouse.

(I know I could just click on the application shown in monitor 2). I know `cmd+tab` lets me cycle through all possible application, and will bring them up in the correct monitor. However, with 8 open applications, this method seems slow, especially if I haven't used the application currently shown on monitor 2 in a long time.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: how would you know to which desktop to switch with keyboard shortcut ? use F3 (mission control to show them)

Comment: Cmd/Tab cycles Apps, not desktops - though if you have Apps pinned to Spaces it may appear to work that way. Basically, there is no way to switch desktop/Space on a display your mouse isn't in, other than switch them in pairs by disabling 'Displays have separate Spaces' in Mission Control settings.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I used the wrong terminology. I have applications open in... spaces? I have multiple spaces open per monitor. I am typing in one space visible on monitor 1, and I want to jump to being able to type in the space open/visible on monitor 2 (I only have 2 monitors).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your original question here is the answer to that.

> switch from one active desktop to next visible desktop on other
>   monitor

[image]

On High Sierra the keyboard shortcut to switch Desktops already exists.

[image]

In my case it only shows 1 since I only have one Desktop.

In your case it should show 8 Desktops (numbers)

Comment: I apologize, I used the wrong terminology. I want to switch from the app visible on monitor 1 to the app visible on monitor 2. I reworded my question to make this more clear.

Comment: no problem, however my answer for switching desktops was correct, based on your original question.

Comment: Switching to "desktop 1" or "desktop 2" pulls up the desktop, not the app/space visible on that monitor.

Comment: I.e., I am using a full-screened app on both monitors, and want to switch between them. `^1` moves me to the desktop associated with monitor 1, not the full-screened app that was previously visible on monitor 1.

Comment: ahh - you didn't mention full-screen. Full-screen breaks all Spaces/Desktops\* key commands, except 'right or left a Space' You cannot go directly to any Space which is full-screen. (\*Note: Apple uses the words Spaces & Desktops interchangeably... which is a bit irritating;) I think your only solution is going to be mouse-based.

Comment: @Tetsujin, that's... kinda silly. Yeah, I haven't been able to find anything anywhere else (and none of my coworkers know either). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Spaces used to work a lot better before it was badly munged into 'Mission Control' - no-one since has ever thought how to fix it. I guess they assume everybody these days is on a single screen, on a laptop. Full-screen Spaces aren't numbered, they're named after the app in each one & no-one ever thought of how/why that is a bad idea:\

Comment: @Tetsujin, is there a way to goto a full-screen space based on a partial name?

Comment: Unfortunately no - did I mention it was badly thought-through? ;) The 'trick' which I stick to resolutely is never to use full-screen, only ever maximise [Opt/click the green dot instead of just click] I then have each app or 'app type' in its own Space, which I can then switch using the key commands. I have 7 Spaces over 2 screens, so 14 'locations'. I keep mine in pairs, however, that still means if I need to switch apps inside a single Space I do have to click. To alleviate that I have one main app per Space, so when I switch Spaces I get the app I need, as it was last-used in that Space.